# How can I save a complete pyqt class and restore it later on on click of a button?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a PyQt Program , based on a stacked widget , where each widget in stacked widget contains is declared in class , I want to save the state of the class in a separate file on click of a button and wants to restore all the contents and settings of the class on another button click , how  do I do that ?
I think QDataStream may be a promising way , but I don't want to manually store each pyqt elements and restore it , is there some way to do it over all the Qt Elements of the class? I have Python 2.7 and PyQt4 on anaconda distribution.

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy way to do this. You have to manually do that stuff.

Comment: @Bakuriu but how come there has been so much development in PyQt in recent past , still there has not been an official elegant way to save the program's state ?

Comment: When developing you have to prioritize useful stuff. The feature you are asking wasn't considered useful enough.  Anyway I believe that 99.999% of the time you do **not** want to serialize the GUI. You just want to save some settings (e.g. recent files, opened files, which toolbars/docks/otherwidgets are active, which styling, which plugins etc.), and for that you can just use `QSettings`. the feature you have in mind would be useful only if the application is like 100% dynamic where the user can dynamically create and reorganize all the interface.

Comment: What "states" do you want to save?  The child widgets?  The geometry and sizing info?  The signal connections?  A widget can have a large number of different "state" information.  It's certainly possible to save all that information, but there isn't a single function you can call to just save and restore everything, since that is seldom what you would actually want anyway.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I want to save all the child widgets and the state of the widgets also , like QListWidget , QtableWidgets , QComboBox   , etc .